# Regex matches but shouldn't

Tags: regex, asp-classic, match

This is my code that checks if there are only alphanumeric characters filled in, but when i enter something like adasd@#$ it still matches and i have no idea why. Any idea how to fix this?

```
Match Match = Regex.Match(value.ToString(), "[0-9a-zA-Z]");
                if (Match.Success)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
```

Comment: Try `^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$` as your regex.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you have matches any string that contains one letter or number somewhere in it.

You need to add anchors to the beginning and end of the string (`^` and `$`), as well as a `+` to allow for more than one character:

```
"^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$"
```

This means "the entire string must be made of letters and numbers".

The `+` also requires that there is at least one character in the string.  This is probably a good thing, but if you want to match empty strings, as well, you can change it to `*`.

Comment: @user2078246, hit the big green checkmark to the left of the answer to mark it correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex `[0-9a-zA-Z]` checks for any alphanumeric character in the input string. Since it finds a, d, a, s, d in your input string, it returns true.
What you need to do is place start and end enchors in your regex. New regex would look like this:

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$
```

Comment: (actually it returns `true` because it finds `a`. It doesn't even bother checking any further)

Comment: yeah true, i just wanted to make it clear that it would have returned true on finding any of these.