# How To Match Alpha, Numeric and Alphanumeric Values

Tags: python, regex, match

I've had a look around and seen people use: **^\W\d_** for an alpha match however, if you enter an alpha character first, then follow it with numeric characters, the match doesn't fail.

Here's the code I'm trying:

```
alpha = compile('[a-zA-Z]')
numeric = compile('[0-9]')
alphanumeric = compile('[a-zA-Z0-9]')


def alpha_test():
#Checks for alpha values
    cell = input('Enter an alpha value: ')
    alpha_valid = alpha.match(cell)
    if alpha_valid:
        print('The cell contains only alpha values.\n')
    else:
        print('Invalid. The cell contains other characters.\n')


def numeric_test():
#Checks for numeric values
    cell = input('Enter a numeric value: ')
    numeric_valid = numeric.match(cell)
    if numeric_valid:
        print('The cell contains only numeric values.\n')
    else:
        print('Invalid. The cell contains other characters.\n')


def alphanumeric_test():
#Checks for alphanumeric values
    cell = input('Enter an alphanumeric value: ')
    alphanumeric_valid = alphanumeric.match(cell)
    if alphanumeric_valid:
        print('The cell contains only alphanumeric values.\n')
    else:
        print('Invalid. The cell contains other characters.\n')


alpha_test()
numeric_test()
alphanumeric_test()
```

Maybe I have the wrong angle on what the match function provides? 
I understand that it can be used to match email formats and ensure they're correct but I thought it could also match character input.

Comment: `[^\W\d_]` means `\w`, but not digits nor underscore. Same as this `[a-zA-Z]`

Comment: Your regex's are only matching 1 character. To match more/all use a quantifier and anchors, like `^[a-zA-Z]+$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the answer to my question - [Regex matches but shouldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15156198/regex-matches-but-shouldnt?rq=1)

Should have looked around a little longer, sorry all.

Comment: Good catch though -- I didn't see anything obvious upon reading your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex's are only matching 1 character. To match more/all use a quantifier and anchors, like `^[a-zA-Z]+$`